# How to sandbox an Rscript command

Tags: r, sandbox, rscript

I am currently in the directory `/root/mydir`. I have an `R` script (`myscript.R`) which contains:

```
list.files("/var/www/html/")
```

I execute the script using the following command:

```
Rscript myscript.R
```

The output is the list of contents of directory `/var/www/html/` as expected.

How can I run `Rscript` in a sandbox mode that prevents the script from accessing files outside the current directory?

Comment: You can't. R can look in any directory that the running user has OS level permissions to access.

Comment: Super vague question. There are many forms of sandboxing and many implementations, some of which are unique to a particular linux platform (assuming linux since `/var` but this may be macOS as well). How's R being executed? Standalone from the command line? Executed from cron? Executed from (ugh) cgi-bin? Executed via `exec()` in a php call? (my bet is on that last one). Also, this isn't an R question, it's a linux/macOS/unix question and you should probably post it on Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: @MrFlick you can totally sandbox R from outside of R.

Comment: As MrFlick said. If you want this to happen, you have to control it at the level of your OS, not at the level of R.

Comment: This might help if using ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292925/how-to-sandbox-applications

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes you are right about the php call. I was hoping for an `R` solution. As I understand, it is not possible from `R` itself.

Comment: @hrbrmstr any suggested reading on this? I'm aware of your pedigree..